# Microsoft Azure : API Access error DisallowedOperation

Tags: azure, azure-management-api, azure-configuration

While performing the Resource Manager API calls for a few subscriptions I am getting the below error

400 Bad Request
{"code":"DisallowedOperation","message":"The current subscription type is not permitted to perform operations on any provider namespace. Please use a different subscription."}

API Call: https://management.azure.com/{resourceUri}/providers/Microsoft.ResourceHealth/availabilityStatuses/current?api-version=2015-01-01

Is this related to the Subscriptions type or the RBAC?

Comment: Do the subscriptions which not work have any commonality? What the types of them?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable "Microsoft.ResourceHealth" Resource provider on your subscription. Please follow below document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services

Comment: When you are not registered for Resource Health provider you get the below error: {
  "code": "AuthError",
  "message": "An error occured in authentication or authorization. Make sure the resource provider has been registered with this subscription"
} Which is different from whet I am seeing